# VHDL How to debounce some buttons after the process was created?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, hardware

I'm new to VHDL . I made a process for my project(a timer) that implies two buttons(M - increment minutes and S - increment seconds) . I need to debounce them . I'm familiar  debounce process  but i don't know how to implement it in my project . 
[EDIT]
My question is how to implement debouncer in my project?Do  I need just to create a new process ?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_unsigned.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_arith.all;

entity Timer is
    port(start_stop,M,S : in std_logic; --Start/Stop , Minutes,Seconds
    clk : in std_logic; -- clock 1MHz
    s1,s2,m1,m2 : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)); --BCD representation for seconds and minutes
end Timer;
--}} End of automatically maintained section

architecture Timer of Timer is

begin  
P0 : process(M,S,start_stop)
variable temp1,temp2,temp3,temp4 : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
variable carry_s,carry_m : std_logic;
begin
    if(M = '1' and S = '1') 
    then
    temp1 := "0000";
    temp2 := "0000";
    temp3 := "0000";
    temp4 := "0000";
    s1 <= temp1;
    s2 <= temp2;  
    m1 <= temp3;
    m2 <= temp4;
    end if;--RESET when you press M and S 

    if(M = '0' and S = '1')
        then 
        temp1 := temp1 + "0001";
        if(temp1 = "1010")
            then
            temp1 := "0000";
            carry_s := '1';
        else
            carry_s := '0';
        end if;
        if(carry_s = '1')
            then
            temp2 := temp2 + "0001";
            if(temp2 = "0110")
                then
                temp2 := "0000";
                carry_s := '0';
            end if;
        end if;
        s1 <= temp1;
        s2 <= temp2;
    end if;-- Increment seconds when you press S

    if(M = '1' and S = '0')
        then 
        temp3 := temp3 + "0001";
        if(temp3 = "1010")
            then
            temp3 := "0000";
            carry_m := '1';
        else
            carry_m := '0';
        end if;
        if(carry_m = '1')
            then
            temp4 := temp4 + "0001";
            if(temp4 = "0110")
                then
                temp4 := "0000";
                carry_m := '0';
            end if;
        end if;
        m1 <= temp3;
        m2 <= temp4;
    end if;-- Increment seconds when you press S
end process P0;
end Timer;
```

Comment: So what is your actual question? What is it that you don't understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is create a `Top Level` module and use the `Timer` module and the `debounce` module as components. Next using port map you should connect the buttons with the `debounce` unit, and the output with the input of the `Timer` unit.Something like this

```
    entity TopLevel is
    Port ( M: in  STD_LOGIC;
           S: in  STD_LOGIC;
           start_stop: in  STD_LOGIC;
           Reset : in  STD_LOGIC;
           Clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
           m1, m2, s1, s2: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0));
end TopLevel;
    architecture Structural of TopLevel is
        COMPONENT Timer
            PORT(
               start_stop, M, S : IN std_logic;
               clk : IN std_logic;          
               s1,s2,m1,m2 : OUT std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
            );
        END COMPONENT;
      COMPONENT debouncebutton
        PORT(
           clk : IN std_logic;
           rst : IN std_logic;
           input : IN std_logic;          
           output : OUT std_logic
        );
     END COMPONENT;
    signal debounceM, debounceS :std_logic;
    begin
     timerunit:Timer port map(
       start_stop => start_stop,
       M =>debounceM,
       S => debounceS,
       clk => Clk,
       s1 => s1,
       s2 => s2,
       m1 => m1,
       m2 => m2 );
    debounceM: debouncebutton PORT MAP(
        clk => Clk,
        rst => Reset,
        input => M,
        output => debounceM
    );
    debounceS: debouncebutton PORT MAP(
        clk => Clk,
        rst => Reset,
        input => S,
        output => debounceS
    );
end Structural;
```